# Create a arrow from cylinder and cone in Blender 2.8 python API

Tags: python

I know this question is redundant and asked multiple times. Though there are solutions available for the older versions of python API, for 2.80 I couldn't find out.

I want to create an arrow using primitive_cylinder_add and primitive_cone_add. As I want to use many arrows, I want them to act as a single object, so that I can translate and rotate as a whole. Following are my sketch, not a working code. I am wondering, how to merge them?

```py
def draw_arrow(): 
   # object length and radius will be fed as argument 
   bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=0.1)  # location will be set 
   bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(radius=0.2)

   **code to merge them as a single object**
   return bpy.context.active_object  # return arrow 

def main():

   arrow=draw_arrow()
   ob = bpy.context.object

   # draw, translate, rotate multiple times as needed  
   n=5
   for ix in range(-n, n, 2):
       copy = ob.copy()
       copy.data = ob.data.copy()
       copy.location.x = ix
       copy.location.y = jx
       copy.location.z = kx
       copy.rotation_euler[1] = theta
       copy.rotation_euler[2] = phi 
       bpy.context.collection.objects.link(copy) 

   bpy.context.scene.objects.update()
```